# I want to switch to the new Activity (when the screen is touched) or (After 5 seconds)

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to switch to the new Activity (when the screen is touched) or (After 5 seconds).This is the code which I am using

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); startActivity(intent); } }, 5000); 
    }
```

Comment: After 5 Seconds It switches to second activity but only the header of second activity appears but the contents of the second activity does not appear

Comment: Read How to Ask a question in SO   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Instead the contents of the first activity appears in the second activity

Comment: For click option i used this method but the result was same as of the above method
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
View.onTouchEvent
        boolean defaultResult = super.onTouchEvent(event);

        switch (event.getAction()){
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
              }
        return defaultResult;
        //return true; //this should work if you need just ACTION_DOWN
     }

Comment: any errors? Look in logcat for possible problems.